# C#: Detect Mouse Events (Enter, Leave, Down, etc.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouseevent

I need to have this event for my cursor interacting with my textbox IN A GRIDVIEW. I tried using TextBox1_MouseEnter or any sort but IntelliSense can't help me. Am I missing a namespace? I have NO IDEA where to start to control mouse events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event on Gridview `TextBox1_MouseEnter` instead try this code.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Cannot read "DataGridViewCellEventArgs". I'm missing a namespace, it says. :(

Comment: without seeing your code it's hard to tell why it's giving namespace error. could you please add your code here for reference?

Comment: try to use this namespace System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs

Comment: here is the link to look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I simply copy-pasted your code in  public partial class Maintenance : System.Web.UI.Page{ because I don't know anything about mouse events.

Comment: Ok now I get a red underline under "Windows" also said not existing in the namespace.

Comment: I'll check out the link. Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to add dll for system.windows.forms, Are you using Windows Form or Asp.net web Forms ??

Comment: Ok so I need to reference. Just need to know how implement code, if that's all that's left to do.